# How to determine if an application is signed with an extended validation (EV) code signing certificate

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I know it is possible to view an application digital certificate by right-click->properties->digital signatures, but I cannot tell whether an application is signed with an EV or a regular code signing certificate.

Since obtaining an EV code signing certificate requires a more thorough background check, I would like to have the opportunity to see if an application is using one or not. For SSL, it is easy as the browser is showing a green bar, but I still have to find a way to quickly identify an application using an EV code signing certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it:

It is indicated by an OID in the Certificate Policies extension field. You must check in each CA's Certificate Practice Statement to find the correct OID to look for.